# Is using Free apps in commercial services allowed by Google Play ToS?

Tags: copyright, software, terms-of-service, fair-use

Here are parts of the [Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/about/play-terms/index.html) I find to be relevant:

> **Free Content.** Google may allow you to download, view or use Content free of charge on Google Play. Additional limitations may apply to your access and use of certain free Content.

Where are these additional limitations mentioned specified? Are there any in the Terms of Service?

Another point:

> **License to Use Content.** After completing a transaction or paying the applicable fees for Content, you will have the non-exclusive right, solely as expressly permitted in these Terms and associated policies, to store, access, view, use, and display copies of the applicable Content on your Devices or as otherwise authorized as part of the Service for your personal, non-commercial use only.

And then it goes into details about restrictions and whatnot.
There are no transaction or fees when downloading Free Content, so this should not apply to free apps, correct?

**MY USE CASE**

I want to create a service for a **commercial web app**, whose functionality would be based on emulating Android OS and, using an automated interaction (bot), launch the downloaded free Android app and start processing information from multiple users with it.

Thanks for reading and help with understanding the Terms of Service.

Comment: There’s a transaction when downloading free contents.

Comment: You are right, [in google's own words](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2851613?hl=en#:~:text=Since%20downloading%20free%20content%20is,have%20one%20in%20your%20account.)